# How does one get a tie game in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've seen "Tie" game results in others' match histories. When a game is considered a tie?

Comment: I imagine if the battle.net servers hosting the game restart during your game that would happen, but since this is pure speculation I'm putting it in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I can say I wish there were either better logic to detect a draw, or a way for each player to submit to a draw so neither player loses matchmaking value.  For instance, I played on a map where I only had one or two land units left, but both of us had flown our command centers off the ground accessible areas, so neither of us were able to win (and all other resources and SCV/probes were all destroyed).  The other person eventually surrendered after waiting for a half hour, but it shouldn't have come to that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Patch 1.2.0](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/2053470#blog) introduced the possibility of a tie in melee games:

> Stalemate Detection has been added. This will end the game in a tie for all remaining players if no players have income, production, or destroyed structures for three consecutive minutes. A countdown timer will now appear when the game detects this scenario.

[Patch 1.3.0](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/2356436#best) changed the parameters a bit.

> The stalemate timer will now reset when any player gathers resources, researches an upgrade, produces a unit, constructs a building, or destroys an enemy building.

Answer (score 4):

I received a Tie Game once in a 3v3 league game.  During the initial load before the match began, everyone was suddenly dumped back to the Battle.net menus (Battle.net did NOT go down).

There may be other ways of getting one, but it looks as though getting dumped due to unknown server issues is one way.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only way for this to happen is in custom maps where no victory conditions are met (or the map designer didn't define any).

I've never seen it occur in a melee (standard) game. If a melee game ends up in an in-completable state (i.e. A Terran player floats a building to an unreachable corner of the map and the other player doesn't have enough money to build a flying unit) it will come down to whichever person gets bored first and surrenders.

Comment: Actually, I think there's a time limit to match length. I can't find the link now, but I seem to recall reading that if a match goes on to like 8 hours or something, it's declared a draw.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, misunderstood the kind of tie you were talking about...

So, besides custom game ties:

This happens when the **Battle.net server is offline** when you finish the game,
even if you can continue to play it won't be able to send the results to Battle.net.

Another reason for this to happen is when **the game desyncs** which also results in a tie,
this one has been actively being exploited by cheaters (desync opponent, let it report a win).

[image]

Comment: Is this speculation, or do you have a reference?

Comment: The issue discussed in that article is people leaving team games as soon as they start and still getting credit if their team manages to pull off a win without them. It doesn't mention any desync exploits.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link... Look it up if you want to, I'm not going to share exploits! [Here is an example account.](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/791268/1/Ownage/)... Masconejos' answer is an example of a victim. Updated answer with screenshot...

Comment: That screenshot and last paragraph have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: look at the "match date" times....

Comment: Good job on down-voting two valid reasons which result in a Tie on the other side. :-)